# MySQL search match at least one word on query string

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm making a query in mysql but i have a problem: this is my column structure

```
|country|
--------
Boston
--------
Chicago
--------
washington
```

The thing is i may have a search item like:

```
North Washington
Boston Easht
South Chicago
```

So i'm trying to match it using the %like% operador like that:

```
select * from am_ciudad where Ciu_Nombre LIKE '%NORTH BOSTON';
select * from am_ciudad where Ciu_Nombre LIKE 'CHICAGO%';
select * from am_ciudad where Ciu_Nombre LIKE '%South Chicago%';
```

the second one makes match because it starts with "chicago" word, but in the case of the query has a prefix it doesn't, is there a way to search by at least one match in the query string?

Comment: What are you asking? Any results that includes north OR washington OR Boston OR East.. or does the answer somehow have to know that its "North Washington" OR "Boston East" etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`IN` method**

Use comma separated list of your search query:

```
SELECT * FROM am_ciudad WHERE Ciu_Nombre IN('North', 'Washington', ...)
```

**`REGEXP` method**

I can imagine the `REGEXP` will be slower, but I haven't benchmarked it.

```
SELECT * FROM am_ciudad WHERE Ciu_Nombre REGEXP(North|Washington|...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your other searches won't match because they do not exist.

If you want to match Boston in the phrase I love Boston Red Sox then you would need to use `...LIKE '%Boston%';` the %s are wild cards so using them before and after the word you are tying to match tell the query that you don't care what come before and after. Your search string of `...LIKE '%NORTH BOSTON';` is telling query that you are looking for `<anything>North BOSTON;` which obviously you don't have.

Hopefully that makes sense and helps out.

S

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure if your version of mysql supports it but its worth trying.

select * from am_ciudad where Ciu_Nombre in (NORTH,BOSTON);

Same for the others, just replace the space with ','